Installing Civivolunteer 2.4.5 for Civicrm version 5.73.2 gives errors and fails
Code
Hi, I know this issue has come up before but the situations and suggested solutions of previous posts don’t solve this issue.
I can't install CiviVolunteer (2.4.5) for CiviCRM (5.73.2) and have tried to install it in a running version of civicrm and also after a fresh install and get the same errors:
DB Error: unknown error and I have changed the field frontend_title to 'Default NULL' in the database so I could retrry the install. The next run the following error showed and the install failed
CRM_Core_Exception: Unable to load template 'file:volunteer-customdata.xml.tpl' in /...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php on line 187
Can you please help?
Ad 1. the details are:
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "DB Error: unknown error"
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#2497
#message: "DB Error: unknown error"
#code: -1
#file: "/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php"
#line: 138
#cause: null
-_trace: null
-errorData: array:8 [
"error_code" => -1
"sql" => "INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_group (name , is_active , group_type , title , add_captcha , is_map , is_edit_link , is_uf_link , is_update_dupe , is_reserved , is_proximity_search ) VALUES ('volunteer_sign_up' , 1 , 'Individual,Contact' , 'Volunteer Sign Up' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 ) "
"debug_info" => "INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_group (name , is_active , group_type , title , add_captcha , is_map , is_edit_link , is_uf_link , is_update_dupe , is_reserved , is_proximity_search ) VALUES ('volunteer_sign_up' , 1 , 'Individual,Contact' , 'Volunteer Sign Up' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 ) [nativecode=1364 ** Field 'frontend_title' doesn't have a default value]"
"entity" => "Extension"
"action" => "install"
"is_error" => 1
"error_message" => "DB Error: unknown error"
"debug_information" => "INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_group (name , is_active , group_type , title , add_captcha , is_map , is_edit_link , is_uf_link , is_update_dupe , is_reserved , is_proximity_search ) VALUES ('volunteer_sign_up' , 1 , 'Individual,Contact' , 'Volunteer Sign Up' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 ) "
]
trace: {
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:138 {
civicrm_api3(string $entity, string $action, array $params = [])
› if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['is_error'])) {
› throw new CRM_Core_Exception($result['error_message'], $result['error_code'] ?? 'undefined', $result);
› }
}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php:187 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:646 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:364 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:170 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:110 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:325 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1231 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
}
}
] ```

Ad 2. the details are:

2024-05-20 07:33:11+0000 [error]
``` $Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "Unable to load template 'file:volunteer-customdata.xml.tpl'"
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#2555
#message: "Unable to load template 'file:volunteer-customdata.xml.tpl'"
#code: 0
#file: "/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php"
#line: 138
#cause: null
-_trace: null
-errorData: array:3 [
"is_error" => 1
"error_message" => "Unable to load template 'file:volunteer-customdata.xml.tpl'"
"error_code" => "undefined"
]
trace: {
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:138 {
civicrm_api3(string $entity, string $action, array $params = [])
› if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['is_error'])) {
› throw new CRM_Core_Exception($result['error_message'], $result['error_code'] ?? 'undefined', $result);
› }
}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php:187 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:646 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:364 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:170 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:110 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:325 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1231 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
/...basedir.../wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
}
}
]

2024-05-20 07:33:11+0000 [debug] $backTrace = #0 /...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /...basedir.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /...basedir.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /...basedir.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /...basedir.../wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /...basedir.../wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main} ```


It looks like Civivolunteer is not compatible with Civicrm 5.7x

Welcome to SE!   That might be related to Smarty 3: look for CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH in your civicrm.settings.php.  If it is there, comment out that line.  If that helps then log an issue at https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/issues
However, this issue suggests there are other problems after 5.60. Although a fix has been committed there has not been a new release since then.
Sadly CiviVolunteer has a load of issues & proposed fixes but seems to be short of resource to maintain it.  If you are new to Civi this extension is probably best avoided.

Thanks for looking into this. Removing that line define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH', '/...base.../wpcontent/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/autoload.php');
creates a next issue with the install script.
I have indeed worked out that Civivolunteer is not updated for CiviCRM v 5.7x and works fine with 5.6x.
Michael who seems to look after Civivolunteer knows and is looking for funding help to update. I'll connect with him further.
